# Udev doesn't match ENV variables on remove

Tags: 16.04, usb, environment-variables, udev

As probably thousands of us I wanted to have special script running when "this one" usb stick is inserted. But also I want to have something running when it's removed - this is pain in the ass.
I did read about issues with correct matching removal here: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/udev-not-doing-remove-rules-841733/

So. My rules are:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi", ATTRS{model}=="USB2FlashStorage", ATTRS{vendor}=="Ut165   ", ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1", ENV{PX2_KEY}="1", SYMLINK+="key%n", OWNER="root", RUN+="/root/bin/key.sh add"
ACTION=="remove", SUBSYSTEM=="bsg", ENV{PX2_KEY}=="1", RUN+="/root/bin/key.sh del"
```

Add one works perfectly but remove doesn't at all.
I tried to use with and `w/o SUBSYSTEM (usb, block, scsi)`, with or without correct `ENV{ID_MODEL}, ID_VENDOR, ID_SERIAL, ID_F..._POOP` and nothing.
On the current stage you can see that I'm creating own symlink (key%n) and tried use that as well with

```
KERNEL=="key*"
```

no luck! You probably noticed also I'm setting my own variable (PX2_KEY) and trying to match by this and... no luck as well... What am I doing wrong... Maybe I'm missing something on rules order but did try making my rule file 10-local as well as 99-local - didn't work. Add works, remove not. `bsg` is set because this is the first subsystem where I see udev shows existence of `PX2_KEY` in

```
udevadm monitor --udev --environment
```

when remove is done. Thought maybe I need to catch first occurence. But tried different too.

Answer (score 1):

It works.

I'm not too smart. The issue was that in the script I wanted to run, I run `zenity` with `--display=:0` as root trying to write message for different user.

Script ended before any "logging" part...

Comment: No, you are smart for figuring it out. Well done!